# Android: text drawn in replacement span not showing

Tags: java, android

I am trying to achieve a count badge-like effect in a text view with a replacement span. I am using a drawable (circle defined in xml) as background as for some reason the canvas.drawCircle method did not seem to work. I want to draw the text on top of this drawable, however, no matter what I try, it never appears. Does anybody have any idea what the problem could be?

My custom replacement span class:

```
public class CircleBackgroundSpan extends ReplacementSpan {
    private Drawable circle;

    public  CircleBackgroundSpan(Drawable drawable)
    {
        circle = drawable;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {

        int textWidth = Math.round(measureText(paint, text, start, end));
        return Math.max(textWidth, circle.getIntrinsicWidth());
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        circle.setBounds((int) x, top, (int) x + circle.getIntrinsicWidth(), top + circle.getIntrinsicHeight());
        circle.draw(canvas);
        paint.setColor(0x0000A8);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        paint.setTextSize(16);
        paint.getTextBounds(text.toString(), 0, text.subSequence(start, end).length(), bounds);
        canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x + circle.getIntrinsicWidth()/2f , y, paint);
    }

    private float measureText(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end)
    {
        return paint.measureText(text, start, end);
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(selected+" items selected");
String numberString = String.valueOf(selected);
spannableString.setSpan(new CircleBackgroundSpan(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.multiselect_circle)), 0, numberString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
multiselect.setText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

And the result:

[image]

I am trying to get something like this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was with setting the paint colour. After I changed `paint.setColor(0x0000A8)` to `paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#0000A8")`, the text was shown.